# Is it wise to use delegates in this instance?

Tags: c#, winforms, delegates

I know delegates have been done a lot on SO but sometimes it doesn't click until I see it on my own stuff.  I look at the following form code and I *know* it can be better.

It should be noted that I'm using a "Model Class" '_model' that contains the methods I want to use.

1. _model.LoadItemType1 takes a string but does not return a value (loads text and builds objects).
2. _model.LoadTotallyDifferentItem also takes a string but builds different objects.
   (both methods have an overload too that takes no parameters - does that complicate things?)

...
...

```
      private string Item1;
      private string Item2;

      private void button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        OpenFileDialog OFD = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (OFD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
           {
           // Removed TRY-CATCH block for simplicity
           Item1= OFD.FileName;
           _model.LoadItemType1(Item1);
           }
        //Some other code to update form etc.
        }

    private void button2Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog OFD = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (OFD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
           // Removed TRY-CATCH block for simplicity
           Item2 = OFD.FileName;
           _model.LoadTotallyDifferentItem(Item2 );
        }
        //Some other code to update form etc.
     }
```

All the stuff around them is similar - I still try-catch the same, I still want it from the button click, still take strings.  I figured I should be able to use something that simply passes the method that I'm running  - i.e. _model.LoadItemType1 and have the one method that does the try-catch and other code.  My **Vision** would be like this ...

```
      string Item1;
      string Item2;
   private void DoThis( /* take my Method namne here */, ref string s )
   {
          // all the code from above but with the appropriate method and string reference
   }

   private void button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
         DoThis(_model.LoadItemType1, ref Item1);
   }

   private void button2Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
         DoThis(_model.LoadTotallyDifferentItem, ref Item2);
   }
```

With this, I could add buttons that load file types and would not need to copy lots of code.

I've tried many of the examples on SO but always seem to trip up when trying to implement them.  I also get a little confused and try to mix different concepts.  I tried passing a Func but it seems to want a return type and my methods don't return anything so I've moved to delegates.

Can anyone help me convert my example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `Action<String>`

```
private void DoThis( Action<String> action, ref string s )
{
  // all the code from above but with the appropriate method and string reference
  OpenFileDialog OFD = new OpenFileDialog();
  if (OFD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
  {
    // Removed TRY-CATCH block for simplicity
    s = OFD.FileName;
    action(s);
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks good ... didn't pick up on the "Action<string>" ... let me try it.

Comment: In my calling code, I'm trying to get this to work but it won't  take my "Action" - any ideas? {Action aMethod = _model.LoadType1;
LoadData(aMethod, Item1);}

Comment: Got it!  I was not doing that right at all ...  (this is now working) ...   Action<string> aMethod = _model.LoadItemType1;
            LoadData(aMethod, ref Item1);

Answer (score 1):

if it were me, I would come up with nice sexy solution involving an interface.  I would suggest you look into that type of method.  But without knowing exactly what you're attempting to do here it might not make sense to do that.

So here is my attempt to work with what I got.

```
string Item1;
string Item2;
private string GetFileName()
{

    var returnValue = (string)null;
    OpenFileDialog OFD = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (OFD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
       // Removed TRY-CATCH block for simplicity
       returnValue = OFD.FileName;
    }

    return returnValue;
}

private void button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Item1 = GetFileName();

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Item1)){
         _model.LoadItemType1(Item1);
    }
}

private void button2Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Item2 = GetFileName();

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Item2)){
         _model.LoadTotallyDifferentItem(Item2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'd considered your approach but I have code after the _model.<Method> line so was trying to do it all without repeating too much.  Interfaces are still new to me but I know the basics - what info would you need to elaborate on your "sexy" solution?